# jQuery resize flash twitch in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript

Hey everyone. Having a problem while resizing a flash object using jquery in Safari only on the following site:

http://www.whittakers.co.nz/

When you navigate around I call javascript events when the flash object needs to change height and when that happens there is a quick flash where everything goes crazy and then it goes back to normal. Really weird, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

You can see my Javascript source here:

http://www.whittakers.co.nz/site-media/main/javascripts/flash-resize.js

Let me know if you need any more info. I have drawn a blank fixing this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When exactly does the Flash object need to change height?  Which button should I press?

Comment: It changes every time you navigate to a new page within the site. The function is called when the new page is fully visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the cause of your problem, but I noticed that setFlashHeight gets called twice with different values.  If you put a console log or an alert you'll see the different values.  This happens particularly quickly when I click on products.  Would it be possible to just call it once?

Comment: Its resizing twice in certain transitions for a reason. The problem is that when it gets resized the object becomes larger than the flash content and the content gets pushed around for some reason. If you put a breakpoint in the setFlashHeight function you will see what is happening for a spilt second. I find it quite strange that it is doing that though because my flash has stage.stageAlign set to StageAlign.TOP_LEFT meaning it should stay sticking to the top left.